# Find the maximum Index difference given constraints

Tags: python, algorithm

In my quest on learning algorithm design, i started practicing questions and there is this particular questions that i have trouble with finding an efficient solution.

> Given an array A of integers, find the maximum of j - i subjected to
>   the constraint of A[i] <= A[j]. A : [3 5 4 2] Output : 2  for the pair
>   (3, 4)

```
def maxIndex(arr):
  max_val = float("-inf")
  for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    for j in range(i + 1 , len(arr)):
      #print(arr[i],arr[j])
      if arr[i] <= arr[j]:
        diff_i = j - i
        if diff_i > max_val:
          max_val = diff_i
  return max_val

A  = [3, 5, 4, 2]
print("Result :",maxIndex(A))
```

My naive approach above will work but the time complexity is O(n^2) with a space complexity of O(1).

Here both the value and the indexes are important.IF i sort the list out of place and store the indices in a dictionary , i will still have to use a nested for loop to check for `j - 1` constraint.

How can i improve the time complexity?

Comment: You can speed it up by reversing the inner loop: Iterate from `len(arr)-1` downwards to `i+1`. The time complexity will stay the same though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two auxiliary array such that the min array stores at index i the minimum value till the index i, similarly the max array contains the max array value till index i (traversed in reverse)
You can find the answer here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-arr-find-the-maximum-j-i-such-that-arrj-arri/

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that I can think from the top of my head for the given problem would be to create a list of pair from the given list which preserves the list indices along with the list value, that is, list of (A<sub>i</sub>, i) for all elements in the list.

You can sort this given list of pairs in ascending order and iterate from left-to-right. We maintain a variable which represents the minimum index we have encountered till now in our iteration `min_index`. Now at every step *i*, we update our answer as *ans = max(ans, index<sub>i</sub> - min_index) iff index<sub>i</sub> > min_index* and also our min_index and also our `min_index` as *min_index = min(index<sub>i</sub>, min_index)* Since our list is sorted, it's guaranteed that *A[i] >= A[min_index]*

Since we need to sort the array initially, the overall complexity of the solution is O(nlog(n))

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, there [is an O(n) solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-arr-find-the-maximum-j-i-such-that-arrj-arri/) which is the most efficient. I will add another way of solving it in O(n log n):

We can think of this problem as for each index i, know the furthest index j > i where a[i] <= a[j]. If we had this, we only need to evaluate the difference of the indexes and keep a maximum over it. So, how to calculate this information?

1. Add all elements to a set, in the form of a pair (element, index) so it first sorts by element, and then by index.
2. Now iterate the array backwards starting from last element. For every pair in the set where element is lower or equal to current element, we set its furthest index as current index and we remove it from set.
3. After all is done, evaluate the furthest index j of each i and the answer is the max of those

Note that for each element, we need to search in the set all values that are lower. The search is O(log n), and while we could iterate more, as we remove it later from the set we only end up iterating each element once, so the overall complexity is O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

There is approach with O(nlogn) time (while I have feeling that linear algorithm should exist).

Make list `min-candidates`

Walk through the source list.

If current item  is less than current minimum, add its index to `min-candidates`. So corresponding values are sorted in descending order.

If current item  is larger than current minimum, search for the first less item in `min-candidates` with binary search. Find index difference and compare with the current best result.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved in `O(nlogn)` time and `O(n)` space.

1. Create a list of tuples of `[value, index]`
2. Sort them by value
3. Initialize min_index to some max value ( `list.length + 1` )
4. Initialize a max value for difference of indices
5. Initialize a tuple to capture indices that has max difference.
6. Now go through following steps ( pseudo code ):

   ```
   min_index = list.length + 1
   max = 0
   max_tuple = []
   for tuple t in list:
      min_index = minimum( t.index, min_index )
      if ( t.index != min_index )
           if ( t.index - min_index >= max )
              max = t.index - min_index
              max_tuple = [min_index, t.index]
   ```

In other words, you keep track of minimum index and because your list is sorted, as you go through the list in increasing value order, you will get a difference between the min index and your current index which you need to maximize.